# Does html forms automatically make a post request?

Tags: html

So I was following a Udemy course on Node.js and one thing that stood out is that forms have a built in method to make backend requests. For instance.

```
<form class="product-form" action="/admin/add-product" method="POST">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<% if(editing) { %><%= product.title %><% } %>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
                <input type="text" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" value="<% if(editing) { %><%= product.imageUrl %> <% } %>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="price" id="price" step="0.01" value="<% if(editing) {%><%=product.price%><% }%>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5"><% if(editing) {%><%=product.description%><% }%></textarea>
            </div>
            <% if(editing) { %>
                <input type="hidden" value="<%= product._id %>" name="productId">
                <% } %>
            <button class="btn" type="submit"></button>
        </form>
```

Doing this will automatically grab all the inputs and use the action to make the url while the method specifies, well the HTTP methods for RESTFUL API. Conventionally we would usually have to specify when to do HTTP requests with the backend more manually compared to this automation.

What I'm curious about is if its possible to replicate this built in under the hood logic with form elements and their contents to other HTML elements without having to construct additional logic on your page that you would do in say React.

Comment: If you do not specify the method, yes the form will automatically do a `POST` request. Forms work as-is. You do not need additional logic in order for a form to work properly. However, when you submit a form, the default behavior is to submit the data to *and* redirect the browser to the given URL. In most modern web apps, this is not desirable, and to change it you have to use JavaScript. Also forms are not "RESTful". The `Content-Type` of a form in most cases is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The body is URL encoded, similar to how you would put query parameters at the end of a URL.

Comment: @Jesse: *"If you do not specify the method, yes the form will automatically do a POST request."* - No it won't.  [GET is the default.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method)

Comment: @David Interesting. I seem to remember it being POST, but then again I haven't worked with standalone forms for a while.

Comment: Is this behavior only unique to forms in HTML or is there another element that has this logic too?

Comment: @user19568466: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Is there something you're trying to build that isn't working?  Are you just looking for documentation and/or tutorials on HTML?